# runcmd in LXC profile ignored

Tags: lxc, linux-containers, lxd

I want to run a command for each container that is created using my profile. The profile looks like this:

```
config:
  user.user-data: |
    #cloud-config
    package_upgrade: true
    packages:
      - python3
    runcmd:
      - "touch /tmp/test.txt"
description: Description
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: macvlan
    parent: enp4s0
    type: nic
  root:
    path: /
    pool: default
    type: disk
name: my-profile
```

The `/tmp/test.txt` file is just not there when I log into my running container. And that is an issue. The worst part is that there are no error messages or any other logs that could help.

According to their [documentation](https://launchpad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html?highlight=runcmd#create-a-lxd-container), `runcmd` does exist as an option in "cloud-init".

Answer (score 0):

Which image are you using?

https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/cloud-init/#cloud-init

> Before trying to use it, however, first determine which image source you are about to use as not all images have the `cloud-init` package installed.

> The images from the `ubuntu` and `ubuntu-daily` remotes are all `cloud-init enabled. Images from the` images`remote have`cloud-init`enabled variants using the`/cloud`suffix, e.g.`images:ubuntu/22.04/cloud`.